# If we upload video to youtube using youtube official video, should we keep the app foreground?

Tags: youtube

I did  a few tests. it seems that if I go to another app, then the video is not uploading.

Can youtube app keeps uploading videos while it's not the foreground app?

Comment: in an ideal world, it should upload it, even when user goes to another app. This upload of data(YouTube video) is a network operation and in Android app, this is usually done in background using something Called Service. When this service is RUNNING, and uploading the content, user can switch to another app and Android will keep this Service running till it's DONE. One corner case might be that this Service is KILLED by Android because of Low Memory in your device and hence video is no longer uploaded. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: it seems that it's not the case

Comment: by the way, it seems an issue specific to your device and YouTube app. I could upload videos without any issue using official YouTube app.